# How to refresh the parent route and it's components when it is clicked again in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-route-segment

I have a **Master-Detail** *container component* with 2 *presentational components* **master** and **detail**. The user will click the link `http://localhost:4200/master`. The **master** component will retrieve the data from the server and display a list of items, and also navigate the **detail** component to the first item in the list. The route will now change to `http://localhost:4200/master/detail:1`.

Now the user can go back to and click the link `http://localhost:4200/master` again. But nothing happens to the **master** component and no new data is downloaded. The components behave like they are cached.

I want to refresh the whole **Master-Detail** if the user clicks `http://localhost:4200/master` again. The data need to be downloaded from the server and display the detail item like the user has clicked the first time.

What settings I need to have in the components or the module, and the changes needed to the routes to make it happen?

This is my current routes:

```
const detailRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'detail/:id',
    component: DetailComponent
  }
];

const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'master',
  component: MasterComponent,
  children: [
    ...detailRoutes
  ],
},
...detailRoutes];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest fix would be to set router option called [onSameUrlNavigation](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#onSameUrlNavigation) to 'reload'

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })]
})
class MyNgModule {}
```

This will force reload when you hit the same URL just as if you navigated to the route for the first time.

**EDIT**: in order for `ngOnInit` to run on same url navigation, you also need to set your router's reuse strategy accordingly.

Inject your router (app.component preferred):

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
}
```

Comment: The **master-detail** container component and the routes are in a lazy loading feature module. The call ```RouterModule.forChild``` does not have a second parameter called option. Should I use your suggestion in the **app routing module**?

Comment: yes it affects app-wide, unfortunately you can't partly apply it

Comment: I tried it in *app routing module** as you suggested. But the ```ngOnInit``` call in the **master** component is not being called.

Comment: The latest suggestion did not produce the desired results. The component creation is going in an infinite loop now.

Comment: should work, check [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vybpld?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Your example is working. My app has a parent ```route-outlet``` for **master** and a child ```route-outlet``` inside of that for **detail**. In my app, when I click the link for the item in the **master** component, both the **master** and **detail** component refresh and down the users from the server which is the not the desired output that I want.