# How to refresh a component declared in HTML everytime its parent component is visited using the same URL?

Tags: javascript, angular

For example, I have 2 components, A and B.

In `A.component.html` there is code as follow

```
<B></B>
```

A is accessed via `router`, and I want B to be refreshed, by calling B's `ngOnInit()`, everytime A is visited, even with the same URL.

I have

1. set `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` in `RouterModule.forRoot`
2. `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'` in A's path
3. subscribe to `router.events` in B's constructor as shown below

```
   this.navigationSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
     if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       this.ngOnInit();
     }
   });
```

But it doesn't work. B is not refreshed.

I guess that is because B is NOT accessed via router directly but as a child of A?

Then how to refresh B everytime A is visited?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68607658/3933927

Comment: @Stavm Sorry but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `onSameUrlNavigation`.
you can Define what the router should do if it receives a navigation request to the current URL.

> app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })]
})
class MyNgModule {}
```

Now,Inject your router

> app.component.ts

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vybpld?file=src/app/app.component.html)

[More Detail](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#onSameUrlNavigation)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think onnginit is suppose to be called directly. Avoid that.
Would listening to this.router.events.subscribe inside B solve the problem?
If not, use a service to share data between them. Inside the service you could have a subject that B could subscribe to. On navigation in A you trigger the subject

Comment: That is what I tried, as mentioned in the question. But it doesn't work.

Comment: B should react to the navigation end. Check that the event is hiting with a breakpoint or console.log. If so create a private method in B that does whatever you want. Call that private method in the standard ngInit method and call it also from the nav end

Comment: Hmm the navigation might not be hitting because you might be navigating to the same route that you are on. If so why are you doing that?

Comment: In my case, component B is responsible for displaying posts, and its `ngOnInit` method call backend to fetch the posts. Every time a new post is created, user will be immediately redirected to component A, which contains B as a child, so at this time B must contain the newly created posts, meaning it shoud refresh after being created via A. Not sure if I explained it clearly.

Comment: Ok. Use a service with an Subject. As I mentioned earlier. Maybe you already have one for the posts? When a post is successful (probably somewhere in A?) using a service metod, the you can trigger a subject in the postService. Component B will be subscribing to it and then it will know when its time to reload the posts. https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/07/angular-7-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: You should also consider not using component B at all. Unless B is used in many places in the application. Another reason to have it could be that A and B is very big with a lot of code and you want to divide the code in different files. But a simple crud page often does not become so big.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem is in the Apollo GraphQL library.
It was using cache so no request was made toward BE...